# Trace the path of vehicles in video opencv python

Tags: opencv, tracking, bounding-box

I want to trace vehicles using Python path as shown in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BP1OMyYuyy4)
I have detected bounding box and have centroid location for every car for each frame. Currently you can see my work on this [video](https://youtu.be/f8-Z1pfugC4) 
I just don't understand how to keep the plot of path while video frames are in loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer  and it is "Ball Tracking by Adran" and how he has used queues to store previous point positions.
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/